# randomly choose the files and add it to the data present in another folder

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

i have two folders(`DATA1 and DATA2`) and inside it there are 3 subfolders(`folder1,folder2 and folder3`) as shown below :

```
DATA1
    folder1/*.txt   contain 5 files
    folder2/*.txt   contain 4 files
    folder3/*.txt   contain 10 files

DATA2
    folder1/*.txt   contain 8 files
    folder2/*.txt   contain 9 files
    folder3/*.txt   contain 10 files
```

as depicted above, there are various number of files in each subfolders with different names and each file contain two columns data as shown below:

```
1 -2.4654174805e+01
2 -2.3655626297e+01
3 -2.2654634476e+01
4 -2.1654865265e+01
5 -2.0653873444e+01
6 -1.9654104233e+01
7 -1.8654333115e+01
8 -1.7653341293e+01
9 -1.6654792786e+01
10 -1.5655022621e+01
```

I just want add data folder wise by choosing the second columns of files randomly
I mean any random data(only second column) from `DATA2/folder1/*.txt` will be added to `DATA1/folder1/*.txt`(only second column), similarly `DATA2/folder2/*.txt` will be added to `DATA1/folder2/*.txt` and so on.

most importantly, i don't need to disturb the first column value of any folders only manipulations with second column.And finally i want to save the data.

can anybody suggest solution for the same
My directory and data structure is attached here
https://i.fluffy.cc/2RPrcMxVQ0RXsSW1lzf6vfQ30jgJD8qp.html

i want to add folder wise data(from DATA2 to DATA1). First of all enter the DATA2/folder1 and randomly chose any file and select its(file) second column(as it consists of two column). Then add the selected second column to the second column of any file present inside DATA1/folder1 and save it to the OUTPUT folder

Comment: I don't understand exactly what "_any random data(only second column) from `DATA2/folder1/*.txt` will be added to `DATA1/folder1/*.txt`(only second column)_" means. If the script picks one random number from a random file in `DATA2`, should it add that to one number present in `DATA1`? Or should it add it to all? How many random numbers should it pick? Can you make a small example where you show the expected outcome?

Comment: yes at first it should randomly chose one file from DATA2/folderx then add it to the only one file to DATA1/folderx

Comment: it add that to one number present in DATA1 is right....it should pick the random numbers=no of files present in DATA1/folderx

Comment: "_it should pick the random numbers=no of files present in DATA1/folderx_" - but that seems to be a contradiction. You list files in `DATA1/folderx` in your question? It'll be easier to understand if you make an example of the files you have before and what one expected outcome would be.

Comment: OK...i am doing it i will send the link...please wait

Comment: please find the link https://i.fluffy.cc/2RPrcMxVQ0RXsSW1lzf6vfQ30jgJD8qp.html  and output should be saved to OUTPUT directory

Comment: It's better if you include a minimal example in the actual question. Not everyone can download from that link.

Comment: does not it support in ur system

Comment: @TedLyngmo i just updated the link in the question

Comment: The purpose of this Q&A site is to provide questions and answers than many can benefit from. Links to external sites tend to go dead and someone who comes here looking at this question in the future may not be able to download that file even if it's still there. Try to make the questions self-contained - and minimal examples are usually appreciated.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you please help me on getting solutions...Thanks

Comment: How can i add it...as i am new i donot know properly,,,

Comment: If you add the information I asked for to the question I (or someone else) _may_  be able to help. "_How can i add it_" - you create a few short examples of files in the question and describe what should be done and provide the expected result. You've sort of described what should be done, but some things you've said seems to contradict what you've written earlier. Some examples could help to clear that up.

Comment: i want to add folderwise data(from DATA2 to DATA1)

First of all enter the DATA2/folder1 and randomly chose any file and select its(file) second column(as it consists of two column).
Then add the selected second column to the second column of any file present inside DATA1/folder1 and save it to the OUTPUT folder

Comment: if there would be no repetition in choosing files randomly it is better

Comment: i think it clears u @TedLyngmo

Comment: Great. It looks clearer now! One question: "_Then add the selected second column to the second column of any file present inside DATA1/folder1_" - do you mean that it should be added to all values in the column or just to one value in the second column?

Comment: please help for the solution @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no code to start from this won't be a ready-to-use answer but rather a few building blocks that may come in handy.

I'll show how to find all files, select a random file, select a random column and extract the value from that column. Duplicating and adapting this for selecting a random file and column to add the value to is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=

# a function to generate a random number
prng() {
    # You could use $RANDOM instead but it gives a narrower range.
    echo $(( $(od -An -N4 -t u4 < /dev/urandom) % $1 ))
}

# Find files
readarray -t files < <(find DATA2/folder* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt')

# Debug print-out of the files array
declare -p files

echo Found ${#files[@]} files

# List files one-by-one
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo "$file"
done

# Select a random file
fileno=$(prng ${#files[@]})
echo "Selecting file number $fileno"

filename=${files[$fileno]}
echo "which is $filename"

lines=$(wc -l < "$filename")
echo "and it has $lines lines"

# Add 1 since awk numbers its lines from 1 and up
rndline=$(( $(prng $lines) + 1 ))
echo "selecting value in column 2 on line $rndline"

value=$(awk -v rndline=$rndline '{ if(NR==rndline) print $2 }' "$filename")
echo "which is $value"

# now pick a random file and line in the other folder using the same technique
```

Comment: what is FS can u please tell me

Comment: @seist Sorry, I meant [`IFS`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS)